# Orbeon: Constraints on UI Parent Elements

Tags: orbeon

Does Orbeon have a way to provide validation on parents of UI elements? I've been testing it with some files from previous work on a different XForm engine, and I've noticed a difference in the handling of the errors on fields without direct UI inputs.

My instance looks like:

```
<set>
    <value prop="1"/>
    <value prop="2"/>
    <value prop="3"/>
</set>
```

My UI section looks like:

```
<xf:group ref="set">
    <h2>set</h2>
    <xf:alert>Bigger Error</xf:alert>
    <xf:repeat ref="value">
        <xf:input ref=".">
            <xf:label>Value</xf:label>
            <xf:alert>Error</xf:alert>
        </xf:input>
    </xf:repeat>
</xf:group>
```

In the other engine, if a constraint such as `<xf:bind ref="set" constraint="count(value) gt 3"/>` failed, the error in the set group would show up in the UI. Is there a way for Orbeon to have this same behavior, or is that a non-standard implementation that I was unknowingly relying on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Orbeon Forms, if you have an `xf:group` bound to an invalid node, just as for leaf controls, by default, you'll see the red icon with an exclamation point in the UI if you have `<xf:alert>` for the group.

If you don't have an `<xf:alert>`, the HTML element corresponding to the group will just have the `xforms-invalid` class in the DOM, which allows you, with CSS, to style the group in a way appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Ah, the red alert icon was showing up at the bottom, lined up with another element, so I missed it. Does it behave the same with a constraint on a top-level `<xf:repeat>`?

Comment: There is no containing element produced for repeat iterations, so there is no such class produced if an "iteration" is invalid. In that case you would need to add an `xf:group` inside your `xf:repeat`.

Comment: Yep, that made the errors show up in the repeats. Thanks for the help.